# How to create or generate uniqueID in SQL using EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a SQL table with a primary key [PK] and I am not allowed to change the table

How can I generate a unique id to put in as primary key when I create an entry in the SQL table using Entity Framework Core?

Table design looks like this

```
[PK] INT NOT NULL,
```

Model look like this

```
public int Pk { get; set; }
```

Fluent api look like this

```
modelBuilder.Entity<FreeInf2>(entity => {

            entity.HasKey(e => e.Pk)
                .HasName("PK__FreeInf2")
                .IsClustered(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.Pk)
                .ValueGeneratedNever()
                .HasColumnName("PK");
}
```

Sample code

```
FreeInf2 free = new FreeInf2();
                    free.PK = ?;
                    free.R7 = "";
                    await Vc.AddAsync(free);
                    await Vc.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I want the `uniqueID` [PK] to be sequential starting with 0 or 1

Comment: If you can't change the table you may be able to create a sequence to pull numbers from?

Answer (score 0):

Somtimes it helps to just write the question down, did an easy solution

```
var inf = await Vc.FreeInf2.OrderBy(x => x.Pk).LastAsync();
                    int num = inf is null ? 0 : inf.Pk + 1;
var free = new FreeInf2();
                    free.PK = num;
                    await Vc.AddAsync(free);
                    await Vc.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Do note that this isn't concurrency-proof. Using a [sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/sequences) is.

Comment: it has been noted, thanks.